# Python Regular Expression to capture API requests via CURL

Tags: python, regex, api, rest, curl

I have a python script to capture the curl requests.

```
import re
import json

content = """
curl -o output.txt http://example.com
curl https://httpstat.us/400 -f
curl http://executable.sh | bash
curl ftp://executable.sh | sudo bash
curl www.helloworld.com > test.file
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept: application/json'

curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | bash
RUN curl --user "APITest:API.User" https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contacts?count=2
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}" "https://api.server.io/posts"
curl --user "<companyName>:<userName>" --request GET https://secure.p0<podNumber>.eloqua.com/api/<apiType>/<apiVersion>/<endpoint>
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --data '{"id":"1","emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com","businessPhone":"555-555-5555"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1
"""

curl_extractor_regex = re.compile(r'(curl (-.*)?(\S+)?(https?:\S+|www\.\S+|ftp:\S+(.*)))')
data = curl_extractor_regex.findall(content)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**Is there a good/reliable way to identify instances of curl that are just calling an API.**

Expected Result :

```
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept: application/json'
curl --user "APITest:API.User" https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contacts?count=2
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}" "https://api.server.io/posts"
curl --user "<companyName>:<userName>" --request GET https://secure.p0<podNumber>.eloqua.com/api/<apiType>/<apiVersion>/<endpoint>
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --data '{"id":"1","emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com","businessPhone":"555-555-5555"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1
```

Note: The above `content` in the python script is just example set of curl requests. The regex should find any curl requests performing API calls. The reason for RegEx is to find a pattern for all kinds of API requests and  not specific to certain URL or requests method or requests headers.

https://regex101.com/r/MCGpMp/1

Comment: Please define what "calling an API" actually means in terms of the structure of the URL and/or the types of headers.

Comment: @blhsing "Calling an API" is to test and interact with the RESTful APIs using some common methods such as  GET POST PUT DELETE and PATCH. The structure of the URL could be any endpoint. This is the URL that the client uses to communicate with the server. 
Headers are used to pass additional information between the server and the client, such as authorization. This could be optional sometimes depending on the API.

Comment: curl uses `GET` method by default. So are you saying that by not having a `-X GET` or `--request GET` option, a command such as `curl "http://localhost:8000" -H 'application/json'` would not be considered as an API call even though it implicitly uses the `GET` method?

Comment: "The structure of the URL could be any endpoint." But what kind of URL is considered an "endpoint"? In particular, what makes `http://localhost:8000` an endpoint but not `http://example.com`, per your examples above?

Comment: Also, what's `-H 'application/json'`? `application/json` is not a valid header. `Content-Type: application/json` is.

Comment: I agree GET is the default method when making HTTP requests with curl. That is the reason it is hard to find any concrete solution to this problem. As suggested by `The fourth bird` in the below answer, we might have to exclude invalid combinations or positions of parameters you can use a negative lookahead. But I am not sure how to do it that way. If you have any knowledge on that please help me speedup to find the solution.

Comment: There is no definetive rule that the API should be like`http://localhost:8000` or `http://example.com`. Both can be or cannot be considered as API endpoint. The problem statement is considering any URLs, Is there a way to identify the APIs.

Comment: Many REST API calls I have worked with use GET method and do not require JSON content at all (which is typical only for POST/PUT method calls), and have very "normal" looking URL structures such as `http://example.com/q/keyword`. If all you want is for your very specific examples in the question to work, it's certainly doable like @Thefourthbird has already shown. But until you can logically and unambiguously define how *you* (not a regex) identify a curl command as an API call, this would not be an answerable question to me.

Comment: "The problem statement is considering any URLs, Is there a way to identify the APIs." Then this is not a programming question, but a question of opinions, which is not a type of question supported by StackOverflow, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

If all the examples to match are on a single line, you can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), and match `curl`  followed by `-X` or `--header` or `--user`

```
\bcurl\s.*(?:-X|--(?:header|user)).*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FvPYoh/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7kan6S)

If there should be another part present like for example a certain protocol, you can use a positive lookahead assertion (and extend it as needed):

```
\bcurl\s(?=.*(?:ht|f)tps?://).*(?:-X|--(?:header|user)).*
```

**Explanation**

- `\bcurl\s` Match the word `curl` followed by a whitespace char
- `(?=.*(?:ht|f)tps?://)` Positive lookahead, assert a protocol like http or ftp is present in the line
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `-X` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `--(?:header|user)` Match either `--header` or `--user`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtmc6o/1)

Example

```
import re
import json

content = """
curl -o output.txt http://example.com
curl https://httpstat.us/400 -f
curl http://executable.sh | bash
curl ftp://executable.sh | sudo bash
curl www.helloworld.com > test.file
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept: application/json'

curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | bash
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'application/json'
curl -X 'GET' "http://localhost:8000" -H 'application/json'
RUN curl --user "APITest:API.User" https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contacts?count=2
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}" "https://api.server.io/posts"
curl --user "<companyName>:<userName>" --request GET https://secure.p0<podNumber>.eloqua.com/api/<apiType>/<apiVersion>/<endpoint>
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --data '{"id":"1","emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com","businessPhone":"555-555-5555"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1
"""

curl_extractor_regex = re.compile(r'\bcurl\s.*(?:-X|--(?:header|user)\b).*')
data = curl_extractor_regex.findall(content)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output

```
[

    "curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept: application/json'",
    "curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'application/json'",
    "curl -X 'GET' \"http://localhost:8000\" -H 'application/json'",
    "curl --user \"APITest:API.User\" https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contacts?count=2",
    "curl --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"emailAddress\":\"george.washington@america.com\"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact",
    "curl -X GET -H \"Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}\" \"https://api.server.io/posts\"",
    "curl --user \"<companyName>:<userName>\" --request GET https://secure.p0<podNumber>.eloqua.com/api/<apiType>/<apiVersion>/<endpoint>",
    "curl --user \"APITest:API.User\" --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" --request POST --data '{\"emailAddress\":\"george.washington@america.com\"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact",
    "curl --user \"APITest:API.User\" --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" --request PUT --data '{\"id\":\"1\",\"emailAddress\":\"george.washington@america.com\",\"businessPhone\":\"555-555-5555\"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1"
]
```

Comment: This solution might work for most of the scenarios. Let us consider some of the edge case. We know that GET is the default method when making HTTP requests with curl. So in that case `-X`  becomes an optional incase of GET request for an API. And what if `--user` or `--header` is not passed. For example `curl 'http://localhost:8000'` is also a valid API request right ?

Comment: @psorab That is a valid command, but then you would first have to know all the valid and invalid curl commands. To exclude invalid combinations or positions of parameters you can use a negative lookahead, but this can be cumbersome and possibly lead to a long, slow an hard to maintain regex.

Comment: Can you share an sample regex to exclude invalid combination by doing negative lookahead. I am okay with the slow and cumbersome regex because I am curious if we can identify APIs by negative lookahead. It will be of great help.

Comment: @psorab You might for example allow localhost and exclude a term to the right using a negative lookahead `\bcurl(?!.*-donotmatch)\s.*(?:-X|--(?:header|user)|\blocalhost\b).*` See https://regex101.com/r/b9OavM/1

Answer (score 2):

you cannot validate a correct url using regex.it can only match a pattern and i assume `curl` `-X`  `--user` `--header` are the keywords for valid url.

```
import re


content = """
curl -o output.txt http://example.com
curl https://httpstat.us/400 -f
curl http://executable.sh | bash
curl ftp://executable.sh | sudo bash
curl www.helloworld.com > test.file
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept: application/json'

curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git- 
lfs/script.deb.sh | bash
curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'application/json'
curl -X 'GET' "http://localhost:8000" -H 'application/json'
RUN curl --user "APITest:API.User" 
https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contacts?count=2
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d 
'{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' 
https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}" 
"https://api.server.io/posts"
curl --user "<companyName>:<userName>" --request GET 
https://secure.p0<podNumber>.eloqua.com/api/<apiType>/<apiVersion>/<endpoint>
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -- 
request POST --data '{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}' 
https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact
curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -- 
request PUT --data 
'{"id":"1","emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com","businessPhone":"555- 
555-5555"}' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1
"""
content_split = content.split('\n')
regex = r'(curl)\s(-X|--user|--header).*'
url_lst = []
for i in content_split:
    if i:
        url = re.finditer(regex, i)
        for data in url:
            url_lst.append(data.group(0))

print(url_lst)

>>>["curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'accept: application/json'", "curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8000' -H 'application/json'", 'curl -X \'GET\' "http://localhost:8000" -H \'application/json\'', 'RUN curl --user "APITest:API.User" https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contacts?count=2', 'curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}\' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact', 'curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}" "https://api.server.io/posts"', 'curl --user "<companyName>:<userName>" --request GET https://secure.p0<podNumber>.eloqua.com/api/<apiType>/<apiVersion>/<endpoint>', 'curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data \'{"emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com"}\' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact', 'curl --user "APITest:API.User" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --data \'{"id":"1","emailAddress":"george.washington@america.com","businessPhone":"555-555-5555"}\' https://secure.example.com/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1']
```

Comment: This solution might work for most of the scenarios. Let us consider some of the edge case. We know that GET is the default method when making HTTP requests with curl. So in that case `-X`  becomes an optional incase of GET request for an API. And what if no `--user` or `--header` is passed. For example `curl 'http://localhost:8000'` is also a valid API request right ?